# Что должен знать начинающий сетевой админ Linux?

Tags: администрирование, linux

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что должен знать начинающий сетевой админ Linux, кроме знаний RFC?

Comment: читать он должен уметь и думать (много). а дальше как получится))

Answer (score 8):

Сильно бы не разделяла администратора Linux и администратора. Сети обычно смешанные (особенно в России любят Windows за его «бесплатность» :-) ).

Выше сказали что для практической работы нужно знать команды. Но для того, чтобы их применять, нужно **немножко теории по общему администрированию и по Linux администрированию**.

Факультативно нужно знать:

1. **Основы локальных вычислительных сетей.**

   Виды сетей по размеру и предназначению. Топологии: классификация, применение, распространение. Стандартизация локальных сетей.
2. **Техническое оснащение локальной сети.**

   Сетевые адаптеры: проводные и беспроводные. Повторители, концентраторы, коммутаторы, маршрутизаторы. IP-камеры, IP-телефоны, IP-принтеры, точки доступа. Шлюзы, мосты, файерволы, NAS и RAID массивы.
3. **Линии связи.**

   Экранированная и неэкранированная витая пара. Волоконно-оптическая линия связи. Радиочастотные устройства. Практическая работа: монтаж линии связи.
4. **Логическая структура сети.**

   Протоколы логического взаимодействия в локальной сети. Протокол TCP/IP v4 и v6. Классовая и бесклассовая адресация, маска подсети.
5. **Построение одноранговой сети.**

   Основные методы построения сети. От рабочих групп к домашним группам. Управление списком пользователей. Разделение ресурсов в одноранговой сети.
6. **Дисковая подсистема и подсистема печати.**

   Работа с жесткими дисками. Работа с принтерами. Разграничение доступа к ресурсам сети.
7. **Построение беспроводной сети.**

   Основные методы построения беспроводных сетей. Формирование беспроводной точки доступа. Протоколы безопасности при формировании беспроводной сети.
8. **DNS.**

   Общие сведения о DNS. Формирование доменной зоны, подключение. Мониторинг DNS-сервера. Практическая работа: Настройка DNS-сервера.
9. **DHCP.**

   Общие сведения о DHCP. Установка и настройка DHCP сервера. Управление областями DHCP, пулом, арендой и резервированием.

---

По Linux для начинающих администраторов дают следующую программу:

1. Введение.

   1. Краткая история UNIX и Linux. Проект GNU.
   2. Общие сведения об архитектуре системы Linux.
   3. Основные понятия — операционная система, shell, консоль, терминал.
   4. Обзор существующих дистрибутивов Linux.
2. Установка и начало работы.

   1. Что нужно знать до установки.
   2. Установка Debian GNU/Linux.
   3. Начало работы в Linux.
   4. Локальный вход в систему. Виртуальные терминалы.
3. Основы управления в Linux.

   1. Интерфейс командной строки.
   2. Основы Bourne Shell (*sh*).
   3. Bash: интерактивный shell.
   4. Что такое сценарии shell.
   5. Управление процессами и задачами.
4. Начало работы.

   1. Как получить справку — *man* и *info*.
   2. Файлы и каталоги.
   3. Поиск файлов.
   4. Обработка текста. Текстовый редактор *vi*.
   5. Управление файлами через Midnight Commander.
5. Установка и удаление программ.

   1. Утилиты *make*, *diff*, *patch*.
   2. Установка программ из исходных кодов.
   3. Система управления пакетами RPM и расширение возможностей при помощи YUM.
   4. Система управления пакетами APT.
6. Работа с дисками и файловыми системами.

   1. Дисковые накопители в Linux.
   2. Создание дисковых разделов: *fdisk*, *cfdisk*.
   3. Файловые системы в файле: loop device.
   4. Виртуальная память (swap).
   5. Файловые системы Linux: Ext2, Ext3, Ext4, ReiserFS, XFS.
   6. Поддержка «неродных» файловых систем NTFS, FAT.
   7. Виртуальные файловые системы.
7. Администрирование учетных записей пользователей и групп. Авторизация в Linux.

   1. Права доступа.
   2. Авторизация пользователей.
   3. Администрирование пользователей.
   4. Управление паролями: *passwd*.
8. Журналирование и ядро Linux.

   1. Журналы, их расположение, регистрация системных сообщений и событий.
   2. Взаимодействие с работающим ядром — настройка ядра.
   3. Доступ к аппаратуре.
   4. Загрузчики систем LILO, GRUB.
   5. Управление модулями ядра: *modprobe*, *rmmod*, *lsmod* и *modinfo*.
9. Резервное копирование и восстановление.

   1. Общие вопросы. Терминология.
   2. Стратегии резервного копирования.
   3. Архиватор *tar*.
   4. Прямой доступ к устройствам — *dd*.
   5. Упаковщики *gzip*, *bzip2*.
10. Процесс загрузки Linux и графическая система X Window System.

    1. Последовательность загрузки. Программа *init* и ее функции.
    2. Сценарий *rc* и система инициализации SystemV.
    3. Понятие службы. Управление службами.
    4. Архитектура графического интерфейса.
    5. Настройка X.org.
    6. Запуск X.
    7. Доступ к удаленным X серверам.
11. Основы построения сетей.

    1. Оборудование и топология сетей.
    2. Иерархия сетевых протоколов. Эталонная модель ISO/OSI.
    3. Семейство протоколов TCP/IP.11.4 Основы IP-адресации, маршрутизация, классы и маски подсетей.
12. Сетевые средства Linux.

    1. Настройка сетевых интерфейсов.
    2. Настройка статической маршрутизации
    3. Средства диагностики: *ping*, *traceroute*, *netstat*, *tcpdump*, *lsof*.
    4. Удаленный доступ — *secure shell* (OpenSSH).
    5. Синхронизация файлов с использованием утилиты RSync.

Да и вообще, возьмите программу образовательного курса и почитайте по этим темам в интернете. Также можете посмотреть пару вебинаров.

Comment: ё-моё, как "многа букаф"! Не запутывайте новичка и потрудитесь хотя бы открыть ссылку в первом ответе.

Comment: Да первая ссылка важна, поддерживаю, но знание команд это только инструмент.А что настраивать то надо знать или нет?Это я еще термины не привела которые нужно знать :)Могу посоветовать для начала новичку почитать оч.хорошо излагаемый блог человека http://www.k-max.name

Answer (score 3):

Пусть меня заклюют медноголовые, но это знать обязан от и до: [unixtoolbox](http://cb.vu/unixtoolbox.xhtml).

Comment: русская версия unixtoolbox: http://zabrosov.ru/

Answer (score 2):

За что заклюют-то? Правильно все, я вот не смог так ёмко выразить. Да и RFC для начинающего - широко шагает товарищ. Базовые команды, собранное под себя ядро, установка mc - и вперед. Главное, понимать для чего это нужно. Если чисто для самообразования, то для начала, наверное, проще построить сеть из 2-3 машин, хотя бы и на virtualbox.Для совсем начинающего админа еще важно понимать как работает сеть - что такое маска, шлюз, DNS, nat, bridge, firewall, proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Из своего опыта скажу, tc знать надо, ибо резать трафик будет желательно. Самба, ибо файл-сервер никто не отменял, да и резервное копирование туда безопаснее. Почту многие хотят, но там все просто. Я для своей подсетки обычно поднимаю SNMP. А вышеперечисленное у товарищей - читаем все про IPTABLES и SQUID. И главное - твердо знать телефон, аську и почту товарища, который готов помочь разобраться, потратить свое время и силы. Ибо книги, это хорошо, а прямая передача опыта (поддержанная книгами) незаменима.

Answer (score 0):

Все вышесказанное, особенно про книгу с командами - зачет. Чтобы стать сетевым админом нужно начать с Linux эникейщика. Командная строка - основной инструмент, потом надоест все делать руками, начнешь писать скрипты и автоматизировать. Сервисов и проектов очень много, сложность может расти бесконечно (например, кластеризация каких-то служб). Собери типа виртуальной лаборатории, чтобы можно было все сломать и не расстраиваться. Про товарища - очень точно, сильно поможет не ходить по граблям. Чем удобны и хороши бесплатные системы, тем они и опасны - что попросишь, она то и сделает. Порог вхождения немаленький.